# DynamoDB DocumentClient query with SGIs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to create an AWS lambda to query a very basic table that looks like the following

Primary Key = "DEVICE_ID"

Secondary Global Index : "USER_ID-index" Partition Key : USER_ID

Secondary Global Index : "USER_EMAIL-index" Partition Key : USER_EMAIL

I am using the Javascript SDK examples and the code below, but I am getting this error:

> ValidationException: Query condition missed key schema element: DEVICE_ID

I cannot get any working example code and their documentation is very fragmented.

my code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region:'us-east-1'});  //new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var params = {
        TableName: "DEVICE_ID_OWNER",
        KeyConditionExpression: "#user = :user",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {"#user": "USER_ID"},  // , "#device" : "DEVICE_ID"}, 
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {":user":event.user_name},
    };

    docClient.query(params, (err, data) => {
        console.log(data);
        if(err){console.log(err);}
        else{console.log(data);}
    });
};
```

> Edit:
>
> This should not be this difficult.  I've tried suing from examples the
>   code below... but am getting an authentication error...

is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource:

> I've looked at the IAM Role Policy and the command is included...
>
> I've never seen anything so poorly documented.
>
> my alternate code (sorry, i've recreated the table names):

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region:'us-east-1'});  //new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var params = {
        TableName: "DEVICE_ATTRIBUTES",
        //Key: {"DEVICE_ID":"098765432109876543214321"},
        IndexName: "USER_ID_INDEX",
        KeyConditionExpression: "USER_ID = :userid",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {":userid": "BulldogLowell"},
        //ProjectionExpression: "DEVICE_ID, userid"
    };

    docClient.query(params, (err, data) => {
        if(err){console.log(err);}
        else{console.log(data);}
    }), callback();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:

In order to query via Global Secondary Index, one must return to IAM and add a new Role Policy for the Index.  My difficulty was that I could "Put" and perform other DB functions, but I finally realized that the error was correct:

> is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource:

was telling me that the Index was outside the permissions of the original Role Policy.

Is there any way to indicate a path for all the "children" of a particular table?

Comment: Yes:  `<TableArn>/index/*`